# Angular js - slide in div on click of element

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, slidetoggle, ng-animate

I am completely new to Angular js and I want to perform an operation i.e. clicking on a button would slide in a div from the right and clicking back again would send it back to right. Basically toggle it.
I know how to do with jquery as below, but the need is to do it in angular.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="clickhere">Click me</a>
  </div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="list">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#clickhere {display:block; width:50px; height:50px; background:#999;}
#list{width:200px; height:100%; position:absolute;top:0;right:-200px;background:#323232;}
.slidein{right:0;}
```

JS:

```
$("#clickhere").click( function(){
    if($("#list").css("right")== "0px")
    {
        $("#list").animate({right:"-200px"}) }
    else{
     $("#list").animate({right:"0"})
    }
})
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/RJJwu/3/

Can anyone please help me with the angular code. I looked over a couple of examples such as :

1) [Different transitions with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108611/different-transitions-with-angularjs)

2) http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-motion/   - in section Slide, 2nd button

The above links represent my actual need. I tried doing it via 1st link, but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** add or remove a class ([`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) or [`ngHide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)) when the user click on the button ([`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)) and do the animation in CSS ([`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)).

Comment: Thanks, would there be any code you would like to share, probably in the fiddle, if possible..

Comment: The idea of the "hint" is that you try by yourself. Write some code and comment, or even ask a new question, if you've got some difficulties.

Comment: CSS transitions don't work for adding/removing elements. Not even for display:none.

Comment: @Haider It's really easy to do with the class `.ng-hide-remove`. Please ask a new question if you get stuck.